# MODX - user profile photo

Tags: modx-revolution

MODX Revolution 2.2.5-pl 
Add-ins: Login

I am trying to allow users to upload profile pictures and to then display that in their profiles, but I have not been very successful. I know the field exists, but I can't find a way to do this.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: what have you tried? some code please. did you change your form enctype? are the server permissions correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Hooks ( http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Login.Using+Pre+and+Post+Hooks ). Example of a similar hook for FormIt - http://forums.modx.com/thread/?thread=47603&page=1